# get resultset from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

i have a stored proc A that contains a stored proc B.

stored proc B does an insert and returns a row of information.

is there a way to access that info in stored proc A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute the stored procedure and selected it into a temp table.

```
Create #table ()....

INSERT INTO #table EXEC your_procedure
```

The only time when it really becomes difficult (and maybe impossible, I've never seen it done) is when the stored procedure returns multiple recordsets (not multiple records) and the recordsets have different fields.

EDIT:
You can can also use a table variable (`DECLARE @my_table TABLE()`) to do the same thing.  In your situation you'll want to try both and see which is better.

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/temp-tables-vs-variables/

Comment: I have a suggestion that we should not suggest OP to use temp table here because as per OP, there is only one row to fetch. Pardon for any mistake.

Comment: I would agree, but to generalize the answer we should show that it is possible to use a temp table.  His needs (or someone else's) might change where it returns many rows instead of one.

Comment: Yes. Agreed. But OP's current need is to fetch one row only. I will appreciate temp table in case of many rows. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You could create a temp table and then insert-exec from the inner procedure call.

[Share Data](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

Scroll down to the Insert-Exec section.

Comment: As per OP scenario, the table table should ve avoided in this case, because only single row will be fetched so I think table variable should be used. Please correct me. Pardon for any mistake.

Comment: This question is tagged as sql-server.  You can only insert-exec to a table variable if you are using SQL2005 or newer.  Using a temp table works in all versions of SQL.  Besides, since there is only one row, the performance (and memory) differences between temp table and table variable are going to be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to create a `Table variable` and insert the row information into it

EDIT:

Please note that it will be useful if not under Transaction and not joining it with other tables and just acting as a intermediate for containing row information as you just said in the query.