# Executing dynamically created SQL Query and storing the Query results as a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a SQL Query dynamically. After it's been created I want to execute it and store it as a temporary table.

`WITH [VALIDACCOUNTS] AS( EXEC (@sqlQuery))`

Comment: And what's stopping you from achieving this?

Comment: You don't know the columns to put in the temporary table create definition?

Comment: @YannickMeeus `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'`

Comment: @ThanosMarkou The SQL Query works

Comment: @LukeOsborne the with keyword indicates common table expression and not a temporary table.

Comment: @ThanosMarkou sorry I meant to say temporary result set

Comment: For Dynamic Query should use `EXEC sp_executesql` staement 

For example  

    `DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(100) = 'SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [dbo].[Product] '
    
    EXEC sp_executesql @str `

but I'm not sure that you want to store in temporary table

Comment: Could you add your query ?

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [get resultset from stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110866/get-resultset-from-stored-procedure)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions for this:

As a first solution you can simply use an `INSERT EXEC`. This will work if you have a specified result set. This could be used if your procedure just returns one result set with a fixed result design.

Simply create your temporary table with matching columns and datatypes. After that you can call this:

```
INSERT INTO #yourTemporaryTable
EXEC(@sql)
```

The second solution would be the usage of `OPENROWSET` for this, which may have some sideeffects.
You can read more about it [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276850(v=sql.80).aspx).

```
INSERT INTO #yourTemptable
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'DRIVER={SQL Server};',
                'EXEC (''+@sql+''))'
```

Comment: 2 or more http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html, also note, these INSERT-EXEC bridges cannot be nested. Also, The `INTO` is optional, its inclusion is subjective.

Comment: Yes insert Exec cannot be nested, thats true. But the second exec is optional.